# How to make Visual Studio Code check entire project for errors?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code for TypeScript/JavaScript development.  When I open a file it will check that file for errors.  The problem is if I'm refactoring (like I move some shared code to a new location or change a name) it won't show me the errors this caused until I open the file with the problem.  ...so if I want to do extensive refactoring I have to open every file just to make it scan the file for errors.

How can I make VS Code scan the whole project for errors without having to open each file one by one manually?

Comment: Would like to know why this was flagged to be closed.  Seems like a direct question that has at least one answer.  If it was inappropriate, I'd like to learn why so I can correct my behaviour.

Comment: All the answers seem to be performing Typescript checks, correct me if I am wrong? I would like to do exactly what the title asks, go through all source files in a project looking for "PROBLEMS" - shown in the panel with TERMINAL, etc. These problems depend on the extensions installed.

Comment: I think you’d have to select the appropriate problemMatcher for your situation. For my situation, any problems that would show up in the “problems” panel are identified with this method (and they do indeed display in that panel).

Comment: This one reason is why I still use Webstorm sometimes

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Figured it out.  Note this answer is specific to TypeScript, which is what I am using.  Here it is:

Make sure typescript is installed globally (I just had mine installed locally apparently):
`npm install -g typescript`

Then in VS Code press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. If you don't have a task runner set up it will ask what you want.  I selected typescript and the tasks.json file will look like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["-p", "."],
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

Then pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> in macOS) will check the entire project for problems and they will be reported in your "problems" panel.

Comment: There's no need for having TypeScript installed globally. Use the one included in the project instead. Just set the command to "node" and the args to ["./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc", "-p", "."].

Comment: This compile all yours source and emit .js files, use this carefully or check better examples below

Comment: where do I add this file? I press Shift+Command+B in macOS and I get no prompt

Comment: on Mac press: shift + command + b worked for me

Answer (score 81):

VS Code (v1.44) has an *experimental* feature, that allows [project wide error reporting](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/13953#issuecomment-583179315) in TS. Try it out:

```
// put this line in settings.json
"typescript.tsserver.experimental.enableProjectDiagnostics": true
```

Comment: Activate this and kill you RAM

Comment: That certainly depends on project size, used extensions and other variables. With a small to medium size project I just have measured around 400-500 MB additional RAM usage (including TS ESLint + spell checker errors), after first load. This is kinda neglectable - though I haven't tested with big projects yet. Make also sure, that you don't include `node_modules` error reporting, which could have huge performance impact.

Comment: Simply perfect!

Comment: @ford04 how did you exclude node_modules?  according to [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13953) there is currently no known way to do so.

Comment: At this moment (Windows 10, VSCode `1.52.1`) it's too random. Problems appear and disappear by magic. The cursor is flickering. Etc. I would recommend to use the Linter (e.g. TSLint or ESLint) to scan all files. For example, automatically before commit (git hook or something custom).

Comment: As of 2023, this setting is also available through the settings menu in the Typescript extension - no need to edit `settings.json` by hand.

Comment: Did anyone figure out how to exclude `node_modules`? They say this is experimental, a dead end, and will not be worked on. But it's still the best solution out there :(

Comment: Same, it would work great if it didn't check node_modules too.

Comment: For now, I simply filter the errors in the `Problems` tab by `!node_modules`, to simply hide internal library errors.

Answer (score 28):

If you don't want to install TypeScript globally, you can do the following:

1. Install TypeScript locally on the project, that is `yarn add --dev typescript` or `npm install --save-dev typescript`.
2. Add a check-types run script to `./package.json`. `--noEmit` means that the compiler will won't generate any JavaScript files.

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "check-types": "tsc --noEmit"
  }
}
```

3. Let VSCode know about the run script in `/.vscode/tasks.json`.

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "npm",
      "script": "check-types",
      "problemMatcher": [
        "$tsc"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

4. To run the tasks hit the F1 key and select 'Run Task', and then 'npm: check-types'.
5. If you add the following lines to the task, pressing `Ctrl+B` will run it.

   "group": {
   "kind": "build",
   "isDefault": true
   }

Comment: Where is settings?

Comment: I get type error from files in node_modules when I do this :(

Comment: You can specify what files to include in your `tsconfig.json` file, @Sammi

Comment: To use this in watch mode see https://medium.com/@thiagodebastos/watch-for-typescript-errors-in-vscode-in-3-steps-aad84f9cdb22

Comment: `npx tsc --noEmit` in your terminal also works if you need to just run it once.

Comment: Good point, @Isaackoz. Note that `npx tsc` has the same issue as installing TypeScript globally: You do not control the version being executed across a team. So the command might break one day because TypeScript released a new version.

Answer (score 20):

Once you have open your project in vs code, open the vs code terminal and run:

```
node_modules/.bin/tsc --noEmit
```

Comment: Excellent! Just what I needed! This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: on an off-note, It would work even better with `--skipLibCheck` compiler option because without it one can end up with a lot of errors reported by dependencies, which is oftentimes undesireable

Answer (score 18):

For the [most recent version](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_migrating-to-tasks-200) of `tasks.json` this is the correct json, following deprecations in version 1.14. Create this as `/.vscode/tasks.json`

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "type": "shell",
    "args": [
        "-p",
        "."
    ],
    "presentation": {
        "reveal": "silent"
    },
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with tasks.json, how do I invoke this?

Comment: @devrobf "Pressing `Ctrl+Shift+B` or running Run Build Task from the global Terminal menu show the following picker:" https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**.
My answer below does not answer the original question, but if you're like me and have found this thread searching for how to turn on `// @ts-check` project-wide in VSCode so that you don't need to add `// @ts-check` to every file then my answer below is what you need. I have searched and searched and kept getting this thread as my top result so hopefully this helps others as well

---

I'm on vscode version 1.52.1 and the answer is so simple and right on the vscode website:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_type-checking-javascript

scroll down to the "**Using jsconfig or tsconfig**" section

Add a jsconfig.json in your project root and add `"checkJs": true`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "checkJs": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/*"]
}
```

You might need to restart vscode once you add it in

Answer (score 2):

None of the other solutions worked fully for me. Here's a `tasks.json` that does, working with vscode 1.67+. On Linux etc. set command to `tsc`, on Windows be sure to run `tsc.cmd` as `tsc` alone will attempt to run the bash script and produce the following error:

```html
The terminal process failed to launch: A native exception occurred during launch (Cannot create process, error code: 193)
```

`"revealProblems": "always"` in the `presentation` section shows the Problems panel on completion.

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "tsc: error check project",
      "command": "tsc.cmd",
      "args": [
        "-p",
        ".",
        "--noEmit"
      ],
      "isBackground": false,
      "problemMatcher": "$tsc",
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "presentation": {
        "revealProblems": "always",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to View menu > Extensions and make sure the [Microsoft VS Code ESLint extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) is installed.
2. In Settings, search for "ESLint > Lint Task: Enable", and enable that setting ([docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-eslint/blob/main/README.md#using-the-extension-with-vs-codes-task-running)).
3. In the Terminal menu, choose Run Task… > `eslint: lint whole folder`.

Comment: This is helpful for catching ESLint errors, but: Not TypeScript compiler errors.

Answer (score -2):

Edit: Since updating to 1.52.0 this no longer works.  It will instead replace the current project files with what you selected...

===

I've tried every solution I can find and I think it's safe to say the answer is: **You can't***

The best I've found is still technically opening each file manually, but at least it's not one-by-one:

1. You can't drag/drop a directory but you can select multiple files (including directories) and drag/drop.  The directories will be ignored and any files you had selected will be opened in tabs.
2. Next, you need to give each tab focus so it triggers eslint to run. (Holding down the *next tab* keyboard shortcut works.)

This is terrible and I beg someone to prove me wrong.

**I haven't found a way that works as well as opening files manually. Each method -- experimental vscode feature and tsc task -- has its own set of drawbacks. The vscode feature is clearly the solution but [without a way to ignore node_modules, etc.](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13953) it's too painful to use.*

Comment: @Francisc0 OP isn't asking about enabling type checking in a project. It's about _scanning_ the entire project and without having to open the files.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right! I'll edit my answer to note that. I found this thread multiple times from a google search on how to do what I specifically answered about. Nothing else was helpful so I want to leave my answer up just in case someone else needs it as well