# Typescript is only compiling open files in Visual Studio

Tags: typescript, visual-studio

I've got a large library of plain old javascript files, from a legacy application, that I've loaded into a Visual Studio Typescript project. I've renamed each file to *.ts and I'm going through them one by one adding type information, so that I can add type safety to the application. There are more than 200 such files.

I've got the following tsconfig file for now:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "ES6",
    "allowJs": false,
    "lib": [ "dom", "es5", "scripthost", "es2015.promise", "es2016.array.include" ]
  },
  "include": [ "**/*"]
}
```

When I open a ts file in my project, Visual Studio correctly scans it for compilation errors and shows them in the Error List window.

But it does **not** scan files that aren't open in the IDE, even when I do a manual build, so the only way to get a project wide error list is to open every single ts file in the project, which is quite annoying in a project of this size.

My main goal in using Typescript is to have the entire code base under compilation, so that if I refactor, by deleting a variable, say, I see right away that I have introduced an error. Having to check each file manually is a major problem.

How can I get VS to scan the whole project and show a list of all errors in all files, not just the open ones?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Visual Studio Code check entire project for errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41702815/how-to-make-visual-studio-code-check-entire-project-for-errors)

Comment: @kaya3: No, that's for Visual Studio Code, which is an entirely different IDE.

Comment: Ah, of course, my mistake. Sorry to waste your time, I didn't read carefully enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never entirely solved this problem, but I can mostly solve my problem by going to the command line and running `tsc --build tsconfig.json`. This builds the entire project specified by the config and I can at least see all errors globally. And sometimes VS does pick up the non-open files correctly.