# Run multiple independent tasks VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Ive got 1 task already in my `tasks.json` (for transpiling ts files to js before debugging with `preLaunchTask`). I'm trying to create another one (to check my entire repo for ts errors with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41709335/10613037). When I made my first task, I opened the command palette then did `ctrl + shift + b`, and chose a task. Now when I do `ctrl + shift + b`, it runs that task I created before, whereas I want to create a wholly new task. How can I do that?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks

Comment: `ctrl+shift+b` is a shortcut for the build task, if no build task selected you get a choice of selecting your build task, the next time it uses your selected task, edit your `tasks.json` to add new tasks and run them with menu **Terminal** > **Run Task**