# VSCode: "Go to Symbol in Workspace" and "Go To Definition" only search in currently open tabs (JS)?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

This seems to only affect my JS files. My PHP files work fine (with a PHP extension of course).

When I do a symbol search (ie. `Go to symbol in workspace`) or when I try to `Go to Definition` (or find usages), it will only look within the currently open tabs. This seems to defeat the purpose of these actions, where I want to search within my entire project.

If I open the file containing the symbol/definition I am searching for in one tab, then search for that symbol/definition from a different file in another tab, it works just fine. If I close the tab containing the symbol/definition, it immediately stops working.

I've tried disabling all of my extensions. The `typescript.workspaceSymbols.scope` setting does not affect the problem. I've tried restarting VSCode. I've made sure that the workspace is saved. This is a nearly fresh install of VSCode.

Is this just how these features are supposed to work? Do I need to reload some sort of symbol database? Is there some setting or extension I'm missing? My understanding was that VSCode came with JS support built in. As I said, these features are working as I would expect for PHP files with a PHP extension but don't work for JS files.

Edit: to clarify before someone asks, none of these files are gitignored

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Visual Studio Code check entire project for errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41702815/how-to-make-visual-studio-code-check-entire-project-for-errors)

Comment: No, I'm not trying to find errors and my project does not use TypeScript. Unless you're implying that VSCode requires TS in order for intellisense to work on plain JS files, I don't think that is relevant.

I only mentioned the one TS setting because multiple other posts mentioned it and I didn't want people to suggest it again here.

Comment: Yes, the JS support in VS Code is just built on TS. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions/typescript-language-features

Answer (score 0):

Despite [VSCode's own documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-projects-jsconfigjson) explicitly specifying that:

> jsconfig.json files are not required

Apparently it absolutely is required for basic functionality.

Adding a completely empty `jsconfig.json` file to my project's root directory fixed the issue entirely. I assume this is a bug.