# VS Code Intellisense autofill/suggestion only working when files are open. How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, autofill

I am using VS code with intellisense. I am trying to import a js module from a js file. Intellisense only works when the file is open that is it gives me autofill suggestion while trying to import the file only when the file is open. How to fix it to make it work so that it gives me import suggestion even when the file to be imported from is not open?

I have described it above. I am using intellisense without making any setting files or changing anything.

Comment: Just trying to get a autofill suggestion like this import { data } from "../../../data"; It works/Intellisense suggests the import when the data js file is open but how to make it work when the file is not open

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Visual Studio Code check entire project for errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41702815/how-to-make-visual-studio-code-check-entire-project-for-errors)

Answer (score 1):

VS Code JavaScript support can run in two different modes: **File Scope** and **Explicit Project**.

If your project misses a `jsconfig.json` it will run in  **File Scope** mode and JavaScript files are treated as independent units by VS Code.

> You can more about the `jsconfig.json` file and and the two modes [in the official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_why-do-i-need-a-jsconfigjson-file).

You might need to create a `jsconfig.json` in the root of your projects to enable **Explicit Project** mode:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "esnext",
    "jsx": "react",
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/node_modules/*"
  ]
}
```